# Align multiple elements in an SVG-container

Tags: svg, alignment

I'm trying to write an SVG-page where we have an icon and to its right a dynamic text (the distance between those two is fixed). The icon has a fixed width and height, but the text can vary in its width.

Both elements are surrounded by a group and they should be centred in there. The group also contains a free text that is also centred.

```
.-------------------------------------.
|                                     |
|             some text               |
|                                     |
|   .----.                            |
|   |    |  blah blah blah blah blah  |
|   `----´                            |
`-------------------------------------´

.-------------------------------------.
|                                     |
|             some text               |
|                                     |
|        .----.                       |
|        |    |  blah blah blah       |
|        `----´                       |
`-------------------------------------´
```

*Anyone to admire my ASCII-skills? ;)*

My approach would be to compile the icon and the text into one group and then centre that one into the parent group. The header text, too.

I read that I can centre texts in a group, but I didn't find a way to align images or actually groups.

```
<g id="MainGroup">      
  <text id="InfoText" x="90" y="0" width="320" text-anchor="middle" font-size="20" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
  <g x="90" y="0" width="320" text-anchor="middle">
    <image id="UserIcon" x="0" y="25" width="48" height="48"/>
    <text id="Username" x="58" y="55" font-size="22" fill="#FFFFFF"/>
  </g>    
</g>
```

How would I do this?

Note that I'm totally new to this SVG-stuff, so I might miss the obvious. If I missed some info you need, feel free to ask for it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no alignment built into SVG. You would have to use the [getBBox](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/types.html#InterfaceSVGLocatable) method via javascript to get the width of the item you want to centre and the width of the container and then do the centering yourself by setting the x attributes of the contained items.

Here's an example

```html
<svg width="320" height="200" onload="go()">
<g id="MainGroup">
  <rect stroke="black" width="100%" height="100%" fill="none"/>
  <text id="InfoText" x="160" y="30" text-anchor="middle" font-size="20" fill="black">some text</text>
  <g id="SubGroup" text-anchor="left">
    <rect id="UserIcon" x="0" y="25" width="48" height="48" fill="red" />
    <text id="Username" x="50" y="55" font-size="22" fill="black">blah blah blah</text>
  </g>    
  <g id="SubGroup2" text-anchor="left">
    <rect id="UserIcon" x="0" y="25" width="48" height="48" fill="red" />
    <text id="Username" x="50" y="55" font-size="22" fill="black">blah blah blah blah blah</text>
  </g>    
</g>
<script>
  function centre(element, y) {
      element.setAttribute("transform",
                            "translate(" + (320 - element.getBBox().width) / 2 + ", " + y + ")");
  }
  function go() {
      centre(document.getElementById("SubGroup"), 30);
      centre(document.getElementById("SubGroup2"), 100);
  }
</script>
</svg>
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. There is an example at [SVG-Wiki](http://wiki.svg.org/index.php/GetBBox).

Comment: @GusOst Then you need to go via [web.archive](https://web.archive.org/web/20111211055106/http://wiki.svg.org/index.php/GetBBox).